# Structural error in my bash script: Unable to correctly list the files in the directory using wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'll make it short and neglect some specific implementation details. Here's the starter code, and it has three cases: 1. No argument, read from user input 2. Two arguments 3. Error:

```
path="$(pwd)"
TIME_OUT="2s"
matchfile=""
reference=""
# CASE 1 : if no parameter, read from user input
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
# User input(detail neglected) gives the value of array[i], matchfile is test__xx
# reference is ex_xx, same as the following situation
    matchfile="test_${array[i]}"
    reference="ex_${ref}"

#if there are two parameters, matchfile is test__xx
# reference is ex_xx
# CASE 2:
elif [ $# -eq 2 ] && [ -n "$1" ] && [ -d "$2" ]; then
matchfile="test_$1"
reference="ex_$1"
#exit in other cases
#CASE 3:
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Here's the part where I list the files in a directory, find a file with same pattern:

```
set -x
echo "$path"
ls "$path"/testcases
for Y in "$path"/testcases/* ; do
  echo " Original Ref: $Y"
  if [ "$Y" == "${path}/testcases/$reference" ]; then
    ref_file="$Y"
    break

  fi
done
exit 1
```

Now in Case 2, the file_listing code would give correct message such as :

```
+ echo DIR
+ ls DIR/testcases
++ pwd
+ for Y in '"$path"/testcases/*'
+ ls DIR/testcases/2.txt
+ echo 'the directory is DIR/testcases/2.txt'
++ pwd
+ echo ' Original Ref: DIR/testcases/2.txt'
+ '[' DIR/testcases/2.txt == DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2 ']'
+ for Y in '"$path"/testcases/*'
+ ls DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2
+ echo 'the directory is DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2'
++ pwd
+ find DIR/testcases -type f -exec chmod a+rwx '{}' ';'
+ echo ' Original Ref: DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2'
+ '[' DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2 == DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2 ']'
+ ref_file=DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2
+ break
+ exit 1
```

In Case1, the file_listing message becomes one line:

```
+ echo DIR
+ ls DIR/testcases
++ pwd
+ for Y in '"$path"/testcases/*'
+ ls 'DIR/testcases/*'
ls: cannot access DIR/testcases/*: No such file or directory
+ echo 'the directory is DIR/testcases/*'
++ pwd
+ echo ' Original Ref: DIR/testcases/*'
+ '[' 'DIR/testcases/*' == DIR/testcases/ex_SOMEFILE2 ']'
+ exit 1
```

Which means, the wildcard is not working, but I really don't know why.

Comment: The files that wildcard expression depends only on `$path`, so that must be different between the two cases. What directory are you in when you run the script? Also, try putting `set -x` just before the `for` line (this makes it print commands as it executes them), and try it both ways and see what's different.

Comment: What's if print for case 1? Also, add `echo "$path"` right after the `set -x`, and compare between cases 1 and 2.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This is how I changed my code for testing,        `set -x
echo "$path"
ls "$path"/testcases
for Y in "$path"/testcases/*` Looks like there's wierd error that the program failed to recognize the wildcard * and see it as a literal char , as the ls returns `ls: cannot access DIR/testcases/*: No such file or directory`, while the correct version should works like `ls /home/jialelin/assg11/prob1/testcases/SomeFileName`, honestly, I've never met with such wacky situation before, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit that (and *exact* output, especially the "+" lines from `wet -x`) into the question in code format? Comments don't let you format it in a clear way.

Comment: I've updated the main question, it's hard to insert code in comments

Comment: Something *really* weird is going on here -- what's running `pwd` every few lines? Also, is the "DIR" it prints *exactly* the same between the two invocations? And just for another test, try adding `declare -p path` and see if the `path` variable has any weird attributes. If that doesn't point out a difference, I think you need to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- make a copy of the script, and start removing things you think are irrelevant; if it starts working, you just found something relevant; if it still fails, remove more until there's something I can post fully.

Comment: Let me explain the need for an MCVE a little more: I'm pretty sure the problem is in something you've left out because you don't think it's important to the question. Part of the point of creating an MCVE is for your benefit, so you may be able to find out what you're missing. The other part is so you can add it to the question, so others can test it directly and experiment and see what's going on.